# Push error from large files even after adding it to gitignore and unstaging

Tags: git, github

The following error is thrown when trying to push commits to my private repo (my own project no one else has access to) on Github:

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (16/16), completed with 10 local objects.
remote: error: Trace: XXXX
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File file1 is 103.40 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To XXX.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'XXX.git'
```

I know this is caused by the large file `file1` I have in my local repo.
This is the exact flow of what I typed prior to the push:

#### 1

```
git add -A
```

#### 2

I realised I forgot to gitignore the large file so I added it to `.gitignore`.

#### 3

```
git rm -r --cached .  # reset all the staged changes
```

#### 4

```
git status
```

Here I knew the large file was unstaged by seeing `deleted: file1`.

#### 5

```
git commit -m "20211120backup"
```

Here I was able to double-check that the large file is removed by seeing the `delete mode 100644 file1`. (Below is a console output).

```
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Enumerating objects: 91, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Total 5 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
[main 6a86997] backup20211120
 4 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 file1
```

#### 6

Finally, below to lead to the said error.

```
git push
```

---

**Why does git still trying to add the large file to the repo, even after adding them to `.gitignore` and resetting all the staged commits?

How to fix this?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by the following.

Check your log of commits.

```
git log
```

It shows the console output like this:

```
commit AAAA (HEAD -> main)
Author: koyamashinji 
Date:   Sat Nov 20 16:49:08 2021 +0900

    backup20211120

commit BBBB
Author: koyamashinji 
Date:   Sat Nov 20 15:32:23 2021 +0900

    backup20211120

commit CCCC
Author: koyamashinji 
Date:   Sat Nov 20 15:24:47 2021 +0900

    backup20211120

commit DDDD (origin/main, master)
Author: koyamashinji 
Date:   Sun Nov 14 18:15:27 2021 +0900

    initial backup
```

Go back to the commit BEFORE adding the large file. (which in this case was `commit DDDD`.

```
git reset --soft DDDD
```

After that, just push normally like below.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "my_commit"
git push
```