# Github/Render/Puppeteer "large file" error even after uninstalling and git rm --cached

Tags: node.js, git, puppeteer

I know this question has been asked [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924633/gitignore-is-not-ignoring-directories/22924673#22924673) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70043929/push-error-from-large-files-even-after-adding-it-to-gitignore-and-unstaging) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33360043/git-error-need-to-remove-large-file) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927098/git-is-committing-node-modules-despite-being-ignored), but I'm running into an issue committing a node.js project that uses Puppeteer to Github and I can't for the life of me figure out why. Since I've been having issues here is what I've tried:

- uninstalled puppeteer locally and removed the .cache folder
  completely
- used git rm -r --cached to clear the cache
- tried git add . && git commit -m "Recommit" && git push origin master

to push everything to Github but I keep getting this error message. At this point I can't even see the .cache folder anymore since I deleted puppeteer and everything. What could be causing this? .gitignore did not include '.cache' before. It does now, but I can't even push the new .gitignore to Github because it errors out with this error every time I try 'git add .gitignore && git commit -m "New ignore" && git push origin master"

```
File .cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-122.0.6261.69/chrome-linux64/chrome is 227.41 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```